# How to select an iframe with Selenium in Python?

Tags: python, selenium

With selenium-python I want to select an `iframe` which has the following information:

```html
<iframe title="Key to fetch simulation results" class="ltiLaunchFrame" name="ltiFrame-1548f8973dbf4d76840c56763e996767" src="/courses/course-v1:EPFL+SimNeuro2+2019_2/xblock/block-v1:EPFL+SimNeuro2+2019_2+type@lti_consumer+block@1548f8973dbf4d76840c56763e996767/handler/lti_launch_handler" allowfullscreen="true" webkitallowfullscreen="true" mozallowfullscreen="true" allow="microphone *; camera *; midi *; geolocation *; encrypted-media *"></iframe>
```

I tried to do

```py
webdriver.switch_to.frame("ltiFrame-1548f8973dbf4d76840c56763e996767")'
```

but it says

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: [name="ltiFrame-1548f8973dbf4d76840c56763e996767"]
```

But I have used the correct name! What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In case `title` attribute value `Key to fetch simulation results` is unique this should work:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@title='Key to fetch simulation results']")))
```

In order to use this you have to import

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

and initialize `wait` object

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//iframe[contains(@name, 'ltiFrame-') and @class='ltiLaunchFrame']
```

you can use the above mentioned xpath to locate the iframe.

**Code :**

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, "//iframe[contains(@name, 'ltiFrame-') and @class='ltiLaunchFrame']")))
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

also in case you wanna come out of the frame, use the below code :

```
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```